# How to retrieve one days data from a log file having multiple days of data

Tags: linux, shell

I have a zipped log file () having 3 days of data.I want to retrieve only one days data. Currently the code for calculating the sum of datavolume is as given below.

```
Server_Sent_bl1=`gzcat $LOGDIR/blprxy1/archive"$i"/*.log.gz | nawk -F"|" '{sum+=$(NF -28)} END{print sum}'`
```

There are 3 logs , suppose all the 3 logs contain data of 06/jul/2014 , how to retrieve jul 6th data from those 3 files and then sum up the data volume?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$ gzcat $LOGDIR/blprxy1/archive"$i"/*.log.gz | grep "06/jul/2014" | nawk -F"|" '{sum+=$(NF -28)} END{print sum}'
```

Comment: But I would guess that jul should be capitalized i.e. 06/Jul/2014